# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java

Tenho o seguinte método de java que lê um arquivo de texto e cria novos pontos(coordenadas num gráfico), porém estou me deparando com o do titulo erro na leitura do arquivo. Ao seguir meu stackTrace ele aponta que o erro está quando tento ler o primeiro nextDouble().
Outra coisa curiosa é que as vezes ele funciona normalmente, daí tento aumentar o número de pontos no meu arquivo de texto e ele começa a surtar.

```
public void readDatabase(String s) throws FileNotFoundException{    
    try {               
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(s));
        String line = br.readLine();
        Scanner trainFile = null;
        while (line != null) {      
            line.trim();
            trainFile = new Scanner(line);
            double x = trainFile.nextDouble();
            double y = trainFile.nextDouble();
            int type = trainFile.nextInt();
            this.database.add(new Ponto(x,y,type));
            line = br.readLine();
        }   
        trainFile.close();
        br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que seja o problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para solucionar o problema eu fiz as seguintes alterei as condições de leitura da próxima linha no meu código, desta forma eu nao me deparei com linhas inválidas.

```
public void readDatabase(String s) throws FileNotFoundException{    
    try {               
        final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(s));
        final Scanner trainFile = new Scanner(br);
        while (trainFile.hasNextDouble()) {      
            double x = trainFile.nextDouble();
            double y = trainFile.nextDouble();
            int type = trainFile.nextInt();
            this.database.add(new Ponto(x,y,type));
        }   
        trainFile.close();
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Existem linhas vazias no seu arquivo? (a última talvez) A [documentação do `getDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble%28%29) diz:

> NoSuchElementException - if the input is exhausted

Eu noto que você faz `trim` na linha e segue para a leitura via `Scanner`, sem verificar se essa linha está vazia. Sugiro fazer isso e, se estiver, prosseguir com o loop:

```
  while (line != null) {        
      line = line.trim(); // Nota: Strings são imutáveis - é preciso reatribuir o valor após o trim
      if ( line.length() == 0 )
          continue;
      trainFile = new Scanner(line);
      ...
```

Comment: O problema com linhas vazias no fim do arquivo foi algo que passou pela minha cabeça, porém eu fiz questão de deletar a ultima linha para ter certeza que o cursor está localizado no ultimo carácter da linha acima. (Isso me garante que a ultima linha não está vazia, correto?)

Comment: Creio que sim. Se o problema permanece, que tal postar uma exemplo de entrada no pastebin ou similar (um que dá a saída correta, e um que dá erro)? Porque a menos que alguém veja um problema no código que eu não estou vendo, ele me parece ok. Por isso ainda penso que o erro deve estar no arquivo de dados.

Comment: Um tipo de entrada era um arquivo de texto simples com dois valores double e um int por linha separados por whitespace. O interessante é que ao utilizar . como separador obtive erro, porém ao usar , meu código funcionou.

Answer (score -2):

> Um tipo de entrada era um arquivo de texto simples com dois valores double e um int por linha separados por whitespace. O interessante é que ao utilizar . como separador obtive erro, porém ao usar , meu código funcionou.

Alguns lugares convencionam o ponto (.), enquanto outros lugares utilizam a vírgula (,).

Por exemplo:

- Se o idioma estiver em inglês o padrão é o ponto (.);
- Se o idioma estiver em português o padrão é a vírgula (,);

Utilize o método useLocale da classe Scanner para especificar a regra que deseja utilizar:

```
trainFile.useLocale(Locale.US);
```

Dessa forma, você conseguirá utilizar a entrada utilizando ponto (.).